# How to generate all integers i, n & i == n (keeping bit length)

Tags: python, bit-manipulation

I'm trying to come up with an efficient algorithm for generating all integers i, n & i == n. For example, for `n == 4`, `bin(n) == '0b100'`, I need to produce:

```
4 ('0b100')
5 ('0b101')
6 ('0b110')
7 ('0b111')
```

How to do this efficiently in Python?

Comment: `for i in range(n, n*2): print(bin(i))` ?

Comment: "all integers i, n & i == n" - this is not clear (to me). The example give a hint, but it still doesn't feel "right". Are you trying to generate all the binary representations of numbers between two numbers that both are a power of two ?

Comment: Is `n` always a power of two? Because that would make it extremely easy.

Comment: @falsetru: this won't work for `n = 5`

Comment: @paxdiablo: No, any integer. Say, 16 bits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can obtain this simply by incrementing `i` and making sure the bits in `n` remain set:

```
def next(n):
    i = n
    while (i >> 1) < n:
        yield i
        i = (i + 1) | n
```

Here I'm assuming you want to quit the iteration when `i` needs more bits than `n` has.

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
def get_matches(n, bin_n):
    # It would be easier to pass number and numbits,
    # but this was the problem definition, so we'll
    # make sure they match...
    assert n == int(bin_n, 0), (n, bin_n)

    numbits = len(bin_n) - bin_n.index('b') - 1
    fmt = "{0:d} ('0b{0:0%db}')" % numbits
    for i in range(2 ** numbits):
        if i & n == n:
            print(fmt.format(i))

get_matches(4, '0b100')
```

Results in:

```
4 ('0b100')
5 ('0b101')
6 ('0b110')
7 ('0b111')
```

Answer (score 1):

I would *start* with the simple list generator:

```
n = 7; u = 256
for i in [x for x in range(n,u) if x & n == n]
    print(i)
```

You can adjust the upper range (`256`) and bitwise check value (`7`) to your specific purposes. The starting value of `n` is used because the *smallest* number that matches that condition is `n` itself.

If you find the list getting too big (the `[...]` actually generates a temporary list in memory), you can use a generator rather than a list. It lazily calculates each value so you don't have to store such a massive list. This is simply a matter of using `(...)` rather than `[...]`:

```
n = 7; u = 4294967296
for i in (x for x in range(n,u) if x & n == n):
    print(i)
```

For sixteen bits (as you specified in a comment), these in-built methods should hopefully be plenty fast enough. On my machine, outputting all the 16-bit numbers (using `n = 0`) takes less than half a second CPU time and an even more impressive 1/25th of a second if you just do nothing with them.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a recursive algorithm which will work on arbitrary integers, not just powers of 2:

```
def matching_bitfields(n):
    if n == 0:
        yield 0
    else:
        has_free_bit = n & 1 == 0
        for m in matching_bitfields(n >> 1):
            m <<= 1
            if has_free_bit:
                yield m
            yield m | 1

def print_matching_bitfields(n):
    for x in matching_bitfields(n):
        print '%r (%r)' % (x, '0b{0:b}'.format(x))

print_matching_bitfields(4)
```

This will print:

```
4 ('0b100')
5 ('0b101')
6 ('0b110')
7 ('0b111')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
n = 4
b = n.bit_length()  # => 3
start = 1 << (b-1)  # => 1 << 2 => 4
for i in range(start, start*2):
    print(i, bin(i))
```

output:

```
4 0b100
5 0b101
6 0b110
7 0b111
```

This will produce the same output for 5, 6, 7 (all 3 bits)